# calling an additional css and js links for a custom page template

Tags: css

I am building a custom page for portfolio. It will require additional css and jss file for the navigation slider... Since that part is contained in the header.php I decided to take the part I need and hoped it would accept my  tags for the external files. Though the link can be seen in the page's head tag, they are not being called. I have looked extensively and all the suggestions points to using wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style() which is an overkill. Even trying them does not help and I would like to call the external links only if someone visits the portfolio page and not burden the rest of the site. I will appreciate some insight. 
www.gransar.net/portfolio

Answer (score 1):

```
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );


if (!is_admin()) {
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_js'); // for js
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_style'); // for css
}
function my_js(){
 if(is_page(page id)){ // or is_page_template(page slug)
    wp_register_script( 'port-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/portfolio-js.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'port-js ');
 }
}
function my_style(){
 if(is_page(page id)){ // or is_page_template(page slug)
        wp_register_style( 'port-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/portfolio-style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'port-style' );
 }
}
```

Use is_page or is page_template to load script and style only page.